# Set starting date of calendar in ngb-datepicker

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am working in an application built in angular 7. I need to show a calendar in my application.
For showing calendar I am using angular ng-bootstrap control - [ngb-datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview)

Now my requirement is that, I want to set the start date for calendar.
For example if user goes to any month then,  calendar should start from the date which I provide.

For example for April month I want below view:

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMMe0.png)

Please ignore colors of dates.

Also I want Sunday to be start day of week, for that I am using firstDayOfWeek property.

Code link:

[Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afaqdh-qjxdut?embed=1&file=app/datepicker-basic.ts)

Comment: I'm not sure whether you want to set an initial date or if you want to set a specific date whenever the user changes the month

Comment: @Antonis yes I want to set a specific date from which the month should start whenever the user changes the month.For example if user navigate to April month then I want it should start from 24-Mar-2019,You can see the screen shot by clicking on link given in my question.

Comment: Antonis,  do you have any idea, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

For starters go with what @[wentjun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10959940/wentjun) described and add the (navigate) event in your template.

From what I understand you business logic is very specific and you need to set specific dates when navigating to specific months.

Therefore you need some kind of mapping to do that.

The `nagigate` event will provide you [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepickerNavigateEvent) kind of data, among other: `next : { year: number; month: number; }`

You will use the month number for your mapping.

Make a months enum so we make something nice and readable:

```
enum MonthList{
  January = 1,
  February,
  March,
  April,
  May,
  June,
  July,
  August,
  September,
  October,
  November,
  December
}
```

And now make the mapping:

```
const DATES_MAP = {
  [MonthList.January]: 20,
  [MonthList.February]: 14,
  [MonthList.March]: 24,
  [MonthList.April]: 5,
  [MonthList.May]: 6,
  [MonthList.June]: 7,
  [MonthList.July]: 8,
  [MonthList.August]: 12,
  [MonthList.September]: 13,
  [MonthList.October]: 14,
  [MonthList.November]: 3,
  [MonthList.December]: 3,
}
```

Now, again like @[wentjun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10959940/wentjun) described, you will utilize the data from the event and set the desired day in a method like that:

```
onNavigate(event) {
  this.selected = {
    year:event.next.year,
    month: event.next.month,
    day:DATES_MAP[event.next.month]
  }
}
```

I've also added you the option to disable specific days per month.

And you can check all of that [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afaqdh-ny2yw4?file=app/datepicker-basic.ts)

Comment: Yes @Antonis, I  have also tried this but is not working as per my requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Options for datepicker can be passed as JSON using the datepicker-options attribute

```
   dateOptions = {     
  startingDay: 0
 };
```

Comment: I am taking about angular bootstrap calendar control. Please refer:       
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by making use of the `navigate` event, as explained on the [ngbootstrap datepicker API documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepicker) (scroll to Outputs).

I am assuming you are using ngModel(template-driven, two way binding) over here.

On the component.html, you will include the `navigate` event binding, and bind it to the `onNavigate()` method, which will be fired whenever the user navigates to a different month or year.

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="selected" (navigate)="onNavigate($event)"></ngb-datepicker>
```

And on your component.ts, we will define the logic for the `onNavigate()` method. The interface for `event` is defined as [such](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepickerNavigateEvent), but for this case, we are only interested in `event.next`, since this gives us the targetted month and year that the user has navigated to. From there, we will get redefine our model, `selected`, and supply it with the year, month, and `selectedDay` (which is the start date defined by you!). On this example, we assume the start date is `1`, and this will result in the first day of the month to be selected when the user has navigated to any year or month on the datepicker.

```
onNavigate(event) {
  //console.log(event)
  const targetMonth = event.next.month;
  const targetYear = event.next.year;
  const selectedDay = 1;
  this.selected = {
    year:targetYear,
    month: targetMonth,
    day:selectedDay
  }
}
```

I have made a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afaqdh?file=app/datepicker-basic.ts).

Comment: Thanks wentjun, but my requirement is something like this, if I navigate to April month then calander should start from 24-mar-2019(as in my case I consider 30-Mar and 31-mar as part of April revenue month)

Comment: is ii possible?

Comment: @suresh Hmmm.. I am a bit confused, but let me make a guess. You want me to select the 24th of the previous month?

Comment: Lets say the user go to Feb 2019, it should select 24 Jan 2019?

Comment: I have update your URL as I need to day start with sunday:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afaqdh-qjxdut?embed=1&file=app/datepicker-basic.ts

Comment: @suresh sorry, what exactly do you require right now..? Start with sunday?

Comment: I need two requirement:
I need start my week day by sunday which can be done using [firstDayOfWeek]=7 and I have done it.

Second requirement is how to force the calander to start with from given Date for example if I go to April month then I want first date of calander to be 24-mar-2019

Comment: "first date of calender"? Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Also, another example, lets say if you go to the month of may. What should the first date of the calendar be? And which date should be selected?

Comment: I have edit my post by adding a link to screen shot of what I need.

Comment: @suresh Ahh okey, so essentially, you want the "first" day of the calendar to be a sunday, right? Thats why it shows the 24th when the user navigates the month of may? I will edit my code when I am home!

Comment: Yes I need the first day of week sunday but I have achieved that by using [firstDayOfWeek]=7.Currently when I navigate to April from May month colander dates ranges from 31-Mar-2019 to 11-May-2019 by default.But What I want to achieve is that it should range from 24-Mar-2019 to 04-May-2019 as you can see in the image attached in my post. Thanks!!

Comment: @suresh I just looked at the screenshot in detail. I am afraid that might not be possible, as the datepicker will not show any week beyond the first week of the selected month. Someone else might have an idea, but at the moment, I am out of ideas. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks @wentjun, could you please suggest other datepicker customizable for such type of requirement available for angular

Comment: @suresh Hmm.. I am not too sure. Have you tried Angular Material Datepicker? It is one of the more commonly used Angular UI libraries too

Comment: Thanks, Yes I know. I will try angular material datepicker

Comment: I have checked, angular material also does not provide this feature.I am thinking to make my own calendar control component in angular, do you think it is feasible.